# Удаление и добавление JSON

Tags: php, json

столкнулся с такой проблемой: Нужно удалить или добавить JSON массив средствами PHP, сам JSON имеет такую структуру:

```
 [
    {
        "img":"",
        "btn":"",
        "text":"",
        "active":"1"
    },
    {
        "img":"",
        "btn":"",
        "text":""
    },
    {
        "img":"",
        "btn":"",
        "text":""
    },
     /* К примеру нужно удалить его.
    {
        "img":"",
        "btn":"",
        "text":""
    }
    */
]
Добавление я пытался сделать таким образом, но не получилось:
    function AddSlide() {
        if(isset($_POST['add_slide_btn'])) {
            $additionalArray = array(
                'img' => $_POST['slide_img'] ?? '',
                'btn' => $_POST['slide_btn'] ?? '',
                'text' => $_POST['slide_text'] ?? ''
            );
            $data_results = file_get_contents('JSONPATH');
            $tempArray = json_decode($data_results);
            $tempArray[] = $additionalArray ;
            $jsonData = json_encode($tempArray);
            file_put_contents('JSONPATH', $jsonData);
        }  
    }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Добавление:

```
$file = file_get_contents('data.json');  // Открыть файл data.json          
$taskList = json_decode($file,TRUE); // перевести в массив                        
unset($file); // Очистить переменную $file           
$taskList[] = array('name'=>$name); // Представить новую переменную как элемент массива, в формате 'ключ'=>'имя переменной'         
file_put_contents('php/data.json',json_encode($taskList));  // Перекодировать в формат и записать в файл.        
unset($taskList);
```

Удаление:

```
$file = file_get_contents('data.json'); // Открыть файл data.json
$taskList=json_decode($file,TRUE); // Декодировать в массив 
   foreach ( $taskList  as $key => $value){ // Найти в массиве  
      if (in_array( $current, $value)) { // Переменную $current
                unset($taskList[$key]); // после обнаружения удалить
          }
      } 
file_put_contents('php/data.json',json_encode($taskList)); // Перекодировать в формат и записать в файл.
unset($taskList); // Очистить переменную $taskList 
file_put_contents('php/data.json',json_encode($taskList)); // Перекодировать в формат и записать в файл.
unset($taskList);
```

Comment: Спасибо! Добавление работает, удаление пока не проверял.

Comment: Вот один нюанс с удалением, он удаляет абсолютно все сообщения: 
` foreach ( $taskList  as $key => $value){ // Найти в массиве  
                                        if (in_array( $_POST['delete_slide'], $value)) { // Переменную $current
                                                unset($taskList[$key]); // после обнаружения удалить
                                            }
                                        } 
`

Comment: А что вы у вас в $value? вот переписанный if  $data = file_get_contents('data.json');
`
$json_arr = json_decode($data, true);
$arr_index = array();
foreach ($json_arr as $key => $value) {
    if ($value['ваш ключ'] == 'значение для сравнения') {
        $arr_index[] = $key;
    }
}
foreach ($arr_index as $i) {
    unset($json_arr[$i]);
}
$json_arr = array_values($json_arr);
file_put_contents('data.json', json_encode($json_arr));`